# how to specify kafka poll records in specific size?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

There's `poll` method to poll `ConsumerRecords` , but It can't specify the record's size , how to poll records in specific size ?

```
 public ConsumerRecords<K, V> poll(long timeout) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only relevant config on the consumer side that I found was the `fetch.max.bytes` property. The doc says the following about this property:

> The maximum amount of data the server should return for a fetch
>   request. Records are fetched in batches by the consumer, and if the
>   first record batch in the first non-empty partition of the fetch is
>   larger than this value, the record batch will still be returned to
>   ensure that the consumer can make progress. As such, this is not a
>   absolute maximum. The maximum record batch size accepted by the broker
>   is defined via message.max.bytes (broker config) or max.message.bytes
>   (topic config). Note that the consumer performs multiple fetches in
>   parallel.

You can also set a limit on per partition fetch using `max.partition.fetch.bytes` property, but I think that's not what you're after.

Alternatively, if you have an estimate on the average size of each record, you can try playing with `max.poll.records` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka actually doesn't support this. You could also try the fetch.max.bytes property.